# Trouble exiting a Sinatra application wrapped in a Daemon

Tags: ruby, sinatra, daemon, exit

I have a Sinatra application wrapped in a Daemon, and I'm having trouble exiting both the Sinatra and the Daemon if an issue occurs in the Sinatra initialization.

Here is a very brief example of the Sinatra class (in system.rb):

```
class System < Sinatra::Base

    def initialize
        if(somethingGoesWrong)
            exit!
        end
    end

 end
```

And here is the Daemon that wraps the Sinatra application (in sinatra.rb):

```
Daemons.run_proc('SinatraSystem') do
    System.run!
end
```

When something goes wrong and the program needs to end, the running stops, but the pid file, and any other things that need to be cleared up, are left behind and not deleted. It seems that Sinatra is finicky about trying to end the Daemon, or the Daemon keeps catching the Sinatra trying to quit. Any suggestions for a clean way to escape both the Sinatra app and the Daemon?

Comment: Why are you using `initialize` with the Sinatra class? Use [configuration](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Configuration) instead.

Comment: Inside the initialize method, variables are declared and a few other methods are called to assist with the initialization. I have run into problems with using configuration in it's place. Perhaps I don't fully understand what is the difference between the two, would you care to shed some insight? Also, I appreciate the insight, but that doesn't seem to touch on the problem at hand.

Comment: Well, on a pragmatic level rather than a technical one, if you can't find any examples using `initialize` and a method is given (`configure` along with the `settings` helper) that seems to do a similar job, you can bet the authors aren't keen on you using `initialize` and have probably got some reason for that. Technically, it's because it's a Rack app and initialization is (mainly) delegated to Rack, so it can handle middleware etc. Take a look at [what the source is doing](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1433).

Comment: Also, just running Sinatra via `ruby my_sinatra_file.rb` (with `run! if __FILE__ == $0` in the inherited class) or `rackup` will daemonize it. Have you got some reason to run it in your own daemon?